# Update database table row if a qualifying token is provided

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, token

My code works fine, but is this efficient code, like on line 16 (commented)? I was thinking to use `$row` and compare with a variable mentioned above, rather than writing another SQL query.

I tried using a variable and `$row['field name']`, but it was throwing an error:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

#### Code

```
<?php
    require('../private/autoload.php');
    if(isset($_GET['token'])){
        $msg = "Email verified successfully, thank you.";
        $token = $_GET['token'];
        $email_status = "active";
        $sql = "SELECT `email_token`, `email_status` FROM `users` where `email_token` = ? AND `email_status` = 'inactive' LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $exist = $result->num_rows;
        if($exist == 0 ){

            // $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $sql = "SELECT `email_token`, `email_status` FROM `users` where `email_token` = ? AND `email_status` = ? LIMIT 1";   // Line 16
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $token, $email_status);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $exist = $result->num_rows;
            if($exist == 1){
            ?>
                <script>
                    alert("Email already verified.");
                    window.location = "../public/index.php";
                </script>;

            <?php exit(); ?>

            <?php }else{ ?>
                <script>
                    alert("User not found.");
                    window.location = "../public/index.php";
                </script>;
          <?php  }

        }else{
            $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `email_status`= ? where `email_token` = ?  LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email_status, $token);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $_SESSION['msg'] = $msg;
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            header('Location: mobile_verify.php');
        }
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Too many queries... If you fetch "active" users, these can't be inactive at the same time.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz so what you suggest ? In first query I should not use "where `email_token` = ? "

Comment: The first query is obsolete, because all information you need is contained in the second query.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz so how about this.
"SELECT `email_token`, `email_status` FROM `users` where `email_token` = ? LIMIT 1";
.....
if(exist == 0){
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($row['email_status'] == "active"){
    then do this
}else{
    do that
}
}

Comment: Yes, that's much better :)

Comment: thankyou @LarsStegelitz it worked perfectly with a lot less number of codes and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Typically, you do not want to be executing a "writing" process on the server-side from a `$_GET` request, but I am imagining that you are sending an email to the user and they are merely clicking a hyperlink so this is a tolerable scenario.
2. I don't know how cryptographically secure your token is (a UUID is a good idea), but relying on just one data point may not be enough.  You may want to include a second data point in the payload such as the md5() encoded email that you sent to, or an expression of the expiry of the token.  These secondary data points don't need to be cryptographically secure, but it should eliminate an accidental data collision or a successful brutal force attack.
3. I recommend that your response *not* give too much detail about a failed outcome.  Giving these types of clues will benefit hackers more than you'll want.

Very simply, one execute an *UPDATE* query and then, depending on the number of affected rows, redirect where desired.  Make sure that you are starting the session at the start of every page where the session needs to be maintained.

Untested recommendation:

```
$token = $_GET['token'] ?? null;
if ($token) {
    require('../private/autoload.php');
    $sql = "UPDATE users
            SET email_status='active'
            WHERE email_status='inactive'
              AND email_token=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $token);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Email verified successfully, thank you.";
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token; // why store this in the session?
        header('Location: mobile_verify.php');
        exit();
    }
}
// missing or invalid submission
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

Comment: so I understood what you are trying to say, and you guessed right the GET method I used is because user is clicking on a email sent to him to verify. 
Also I did not properly understood your point 2, like should I send email (encrypted) or what?

And for your question in code, I'm storing the token in session so that when user goes to mobile_verify that token is used as and identifier for the particular user. 
Also session start is in autoload.php.

Comment: First, I merely mean for you to specify the user's email address as `&email=their_email@example.com` alongside the token that is already in the querystring of the link in the email. Using `md5` to encode the email address into a string consisting of numbers and letters avoids url encoding problems (but is certainly not the only way to overcome this challenge). Second, I don't understand why someone being sent to this page AND successfully activating the token would have any further use for the token.  If you are using it as a permanent identifier, okay.

Comment: so I should specify user email in update query with token? And after successful email verify user need to verify there mobile so I'm redirecting them to the mobile page with the token so that mobile number entered by user can be verified as the token is unique so only one row have the same token and mobile number.

Comment: Aaaaah.  Okay, okay, I get it.  "mobile number verify" is less ambiguous than "mobile verify".

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion is to reduce the number of queries by combining the aspects of both. A user can't be "active" or "inactive" at the same time, so there is no need to do two queries.

The first query is obsolete, because all information is contained in the second query.

(please also read comments of the initial post)

Comment: No.  Please add all of your code and advice here so that all of the comments under the question can be removed.  This is a Q&A not a Q&A&C.  Ideally there should be no comments on a page because the question contains all necessary info and all answers contain all of the necessary advice.

Comment: Oh.. Sameer came to the solution on his own, I didn't provide code, only the suggestion.. sorry if I misunderstood you.